# Can you install ant on a shared host that already has java?

Tags: java, ant

I only have access to my home directory. I was hoping I could install it there some place.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks!

> **.bash_profile**

```
 export SYS_="/home/${LOGNAME}/root"
 export SYS_LIB="${SYS_}/lib"
 #ant appends /bin/java to whatever I set JAVA_HOME to
 export JAVA_HOME='/usr'
 export JAVA_FULL_HOME='/usr/bin/java'
 export ANT_HOME=${SYS_LIB}/ant-1.8.2/bin
```

> **UPDATE >**
>
> I've got ant on my box but its having
>   issues... looks like whatever I set to
>   JAVA_HOME it appends "/bin/java" to
>   it... so that's annoying... took me
>   forever to figure that out
>
> **but now I'm getting this error >**
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

Comment: Ok just figured it out.. Stupid web host was appending crap to my paths!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be able to - it is a self contained program that just needs JAVA_HOME set.

Comment: ie just copy it to where you want it

Comment: so far this isnt working for me. I added ant to a dir i created /lib/ant and I added ant_home and java_home but ant is giving me an error that it cant find java =/

Comment: What is the value of your `JAVA_HOME` variable?

Comment: And if you `cd $JAVA_HOME` can you run `./java --version`?

Comment: I've got ant on my box but its having issues... looks like whatever I set to JAVA_HOME it appends "/bin/java" to it... so that's annoying... took me forever to figure that out...
I think theres some issue with how the web host has java setup... should I just install my own local java?